# Sort data with multiple criteria including MATCH

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, match, array-formulas

I'm honestly not 100% sure if this is the right place to ask but I have to give it a try so I'm trying to sort by curse and by A -> Z the names but I have try plenty of ways and I never get the correct format and I have google it and they just keep giving useless answers that is not for this specific case. [image]

As you can see I made a custom sort for the curse but I still have no idea how or where to add the A -> Z for the names I always get it wrong and it tells me is wrong. Any advice ?

I have done plenty attempts trying to format it the right way buuut always end in failure an example:
[image]

Formula: =ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(DATA!A2:BY101,match(DATA!P2:P101,{"1º";"2º";"3º";"4º";"5º";"6º";"7º";"8º";"9º";"10º";"11º";"12º"},0),TRUE))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(DATA!A2:BY101, MATCH(DATA!P2:P101, 
 {"1º";"2º";"3º";"4º";"5º";"6º";"7º";"8º";"9º";"10º";"11º";"12º"}, 0), 1, 2, 1))
```

Comment: Can you explain me why this works ? I though you had to select the data first and then set up parameters

Comment: @Pankake sure, but you can continue with parameters. in this case, we sort the given range first by your MATCH formula in ascending (1) order and then sort by 2nd column of the given range also in ascending (1) order.

Comment: The bit I do not understand is    ) , 1, 2, 1)) Like what does that even mean how I know is selecting the right column I know 0 and 1 at the end means ascending or descending, but I don't get the 1,2,1 what parameters are suppose to be those, the 2 makes me think is selecting B right? or am I wrong ?

Comment: @Pankake yes. 1's are Ascending. 0's instead of those 1's would be Descending. and that 2 = B column